# Changing a character variable to a date variable in R

Tags: r, date, dplyr, character, lubridate

I have a variable in the right format to delineate Year-Quarter (ie "2015 Q1")  however, it is stored in R as a character and I am trying to complete a time-series analysis that requires I have dates. My data is collected quarterly, hence the quarter format.

I have tried using the lubridate and zoo packages to convert the character variable into a recognizable date.

```
str(Qtotal)
'data.frame':   24 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Quarter  : chr  "2017 Q1" "2017 Q2" "2017 Q3" "2017 Q4" ...
 $ date     : Date, format: NA NA NA ...

Qtotal$date <- as.Date(Qtotal$Quarter, format = "%m-%d-%y")
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Other things I've tried:

```
total$date<-as.Date(parse_date_time(Qtotal$Quarter, c('mdy')))
```

Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.

```
Qtotal$date<-as.Date(parse_date_time(Qtotal$create_date, c('mdy')))
```

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, date, value = numeric(0)) : 
>     replacement has 0 rows, data has 24

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can convert to 'yearqtr' class with `as.yearqtr` (from `zoo`) and coerce it to `Date`

```
library(zoo)
as.Date(as.yearqtr(Qtotal$Quarter))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was extremely helpful.